# Handling events in between components in vue3 under the same parent component

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, vuejs3, event-bus

I'm trying to build a component with multiple child components that pass around events. Each component will listen to the next in the chain and handle the event with some logic and pass another event corresponding to it and the next component in the chain will handle it until the last one in the flow chain.

I've tried multiple solutions and seem to not figure out the way to do it in vue yet.
if you have any idea of how to implement something like that I would appreciate it.

fyi, I'm using vue 3 with ts and vite. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The solution will either use props and emits, or a global store like Pinia.  The implementation depends on your app, of which we know very little about.  If you have a specific problem with your implementation you'll need to post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for others to help give more specific debugging help/advice.

Comment: @yoduh that is fair enough. I think Pinia is the way I'll go at it atm. It's my first project in vue so I'm trying to learn the "meta" of how to implement certain things. Do you have a specific way you would implement it with Pinia? I'm looking into the possibility of using mitt but trying to see if there is an easy native vue way to do so.